# How to get daily difference in time series values when time delta index is irregular in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataframe containing a time series indexed by time but with irregular time deltas as below

```
df
time                  x
2018-08-18 17:45:08   1.4562
2018-08-18 17:46:55   1.4901
2018-08-18 17:51:21   1.8012
...
2020-03-21 04:17:19   0.7623
2020-03-21 05:01:02   0.8231
2020-03-21 05:02:34   0.8038
```

What I want to do is get the **daily difference between the two (chronologically) closest values**, i.e. the closest time the next day. For example, if we have a sample at time 2018-08-18 17:45:08, and the next day we do not have a sample at the same time, but the closest sample is at, say, 2018-08-19 17:44:29, then I want to get the difference in `x` between these two times. How is that possible in pandas?

- There will always be a sample for every single day between first day and last day in the time series.
- The difference should be taken as (current x) - (past x) e.g. x_day2 - x_day1
- The output's first `n` rows will be `NaN` given how the difference is taken, where `n` is the number of samples in the first day

**EDIT:** The code below works if the time deltas are regular

```
def get_daily_diff(data):
    """
    Calculate daily difference in time series

    Args:
        data (pandas.Series): a pandas series of time series values indexed by pandas.Timestamp

    Returns:
        pandas.Series: daily difference in values
    """
    df0 = data.index.searchsorted(data.index - pd.Timedelta(days=1))
    df0 = df0[df0 > 0]
    df0 = pd.Series(data.index[df0 - 1], index=data.index[data.shape[0] - df0.shape[0]:])
    out = data.loc[df0.index] - data.loc[df0.values]
    return out
```

However, if using irregular time delats, a `ValueError` is thrown when defining the variable `out` as we get a length mismatch between `data.loc[df0.index]` and `data.loc[df0.values]`. So the issue is to expand this function to work when the time deltas are irregular.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example of your code [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that other users can reproduce your problem? Thank you!

Comment: Nice question. What's the expected output? Do you want to get the closest-time-tomorrow for each row in your data? What's the expected output for the last day?

Comment: @Roy2012 yes closest time tomorrow, thanks for asking. I made edits to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `pd.merge_asof` with `direction='nearest'`:

```
df['time_1d'] = df['time']+pd.Timedelta('1D')
tmp = pd.merge_asof(df, df, left_on='time', right_on ='time_1d',
           direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('12H'), suffixes=('', '_y'))
tmp['delta'] = tmp['x_y'] - tmp['x']
tmp = tmp[['time', 'x', 'delta']]
```

Here I have used a tolerance of 12H to make sure to have NaN for first days but you could use a more appropriate value.

Comment: This seems really close, but we want to take the difference `x_day2 - x_day1`, so actually the **first** `n` days in the output are `NaN` - sorry for the confusion, I edited the question to explain that. How could we modify your solution to do that?

Comment: @PyRsquared Just switch the time columns in the merge. Already done in my last edit.